# Does TypeScript have a way to require property A NAND property B?

Tags: typescript

The desired behavior is as follows:

```js
const a: MyType = { foo: '' };             // should be OK
const b: MyType = { foo: '', propA: '' };  // should be OK
const c: MyType = { foo: '', propB: '' };  // should be OK
const d: MyType = { foo: '', propA: '', propB: '' }; // should be an error
```

Supplying `propA` or `propB` or neither should be ok, but supplying both should give an error. I have seen many similar problems here on Stack Overflow, but most ask for an OR relationship or an XOR relationship, and not a NAND one.

How would I define `MyType` to achieve this desired behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit clumsy but this should work:

```
interface FooType {
    foo: string;
}
interface FooPropAType  extends FooType {
    propA:string;
}
interface FooPropBType extends FooType {
    propB: string;
}
type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };
type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;

type MyType = XOR<FooType, XOR<FooPropAType, FooPropBType>>;

const a: MyType = { foo: '' };             // should be OK
const b: MyType = { foo: '', propA: '' };  // should be OK
const c: MyType = { foo: '', propB: '' };  // should be OK
const d: MyType = { foo: '', propA: '', propB: '' }; // should be an error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0BUCeAHFAbwChkzkZMAuZAZzClAHMBuYgX2NElkRQ3QAFKOjwBBXATIQAHpBAATWmkySipcnhHiq9RiFYcu4aPCQqh2gEJrks+Uou2S5ZFtFWae5m05h8KADqwGAAFugArmAAPFgANMgAqgB8yAC8yITIANqCyKDIAKIyCAA2EQoQ0QDWEDjoMMjxyLX1jSkAugD8NCAQAG7QyOxs-lIAGgDyAEqxCSnpyAAUWMgAPkkAlHZyEIrK6ABGAFYQCGDIXcvBYZExzQsAZFvr1yHhUdGJCVipz1jbGirDaJNjEMYoACyOFsGSmswEagS8OiAmEogkAQSaOsamSyTBCHQIHoyDgNGhsMyFGoyAA5HThixXCzXAB6Nl0D6lBTIQ4oSYAaWIRJJF0OFJhAUWWUo6BoDIS7h09MZIzIHK5kR5fIFwtFpIQkqpstpirc1gVauZyE1tG5vP5yCFIuJpIUxulGVN8tVSu0Yit-o8VqZts59u1jpQcBAdigIigxCAA)

Comment: Does somebody have a "cleaner" option ?